# R data table usage as parameter in package

Tags: r, package, data.table

I have a problem using a data.table as a parameter to a function.

If I define the function in the script I'm working in it works - see fn_good.

If I define the function (identically) as part of a package I've made it won't work fully. It seems that the column names are not recognized. Commands within the function such as 'tables()' or x[1:5,1:2] work fine. It is just the column names can't be used as they were in fn_good.

The other functions in my package work ok.

Any Ideas?

many thanks

R.version 3.0.0

```
cd<-data.table(PY=1992:2001,DV=1:10,IN=2000)

fn_good<-function(x) {x[1:5, list(PY, DV)]}

fn_good(x=cd)
     PY DV
1: 1992  1
2: 1993  2
3: 1994  3
4: 1995  4
5: 1996  5


fn_in_Package_Bad
function (x) 
{
    x[1:5, list(PY, DV)] #identical to above
}
<environment: namespace:RBasicChainLadder>

fn_in_Package_Bad(x=cd)
Error in `[.data.frame`(x, i, j) : object 'PY' not found
```

Comment: Can you show us your `Description` file? Your package should be `data.table` aware, else `[.data.table` will redirect it to `[.data.frame`.

Comment: Also it's better to post the output of `sessionInfo()` instead of only stating your R-version. Just a suggestion.

Comment: @Arun thanks you pointed me in right direction about package not being data.table aware

Answer (score 1):

To make the package data.table aware I had to add

```
depends: data.table
```

to the package description file